# Array initialization problem

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var intrebari = new Array();
var i = 0;
intrebari[i]['enunt'] = 'test';
alert(intrebari[i]['enunt']);
```

The problem is that when I run it it says that `intrebari` is undefined. Why?

Comment: Note that just `[]` is the same as "new Array()", and `{}` is the same as "new Object()".  Just to save you some typing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var intrebari = new Array();
var i = 0;
intrebari[i] = new Object()
intrebari[i]['enunt'] = 'test';
alert(intrebari[i]['enunt']);
```

Comment: No, it shouldn't be a new Array; it's being used with a string key, so it should more likely be an object.

Comment: @Pointy : fixed it. But is this the only reason of using object instead of array.

Comment: Well, arrays have their own behaviors. It *works* to use an array as an object, because arrays *are* objects. But there can be strange effects sometimes if the programmer is not very aware of exactly how things work.

Answer (score 2):

Yes interbari[0] is null , so it cannot be object - and for adding into array use push instead of indexes

```
var intrebari = [];
intrebari.push({ 'enunt': 'test' });
alert(intrebari[i]['enunt']);
```

This will work

Comment: Alternatively, `intrebari[i]` could be set to just `{}`, and then that assignment in the original would work. But this answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You need to assign something to `intrebari[i]` before you can access any properties of it, "by default" its value is `undefined` that doesn't have any properties. For example:

```
intrebari[i] = new Object();
intrebari[i]["enunt"] = "test";
alert(intrebari[i]["enunt"]);
```